# How can I set the name attribute of a WTForm Field, without changing the variable name?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-wtforms

I am trying to set the name of these WTForm fields without having to change the name of the variables themselves. Any help is appreciated.

```
class AddProblemForm(Form):
    problem_point_value_data = [[10, 20, 30], [40, 50, 60], [70, 80, 90, 100], [120, 140, 160, 180, 200]]
    problemName = StringField('problemName',_name="problemName", validators=[validators.DataRequired(), validators.Length(min=2, max=64)])
    problem_description = PageDownField('problemDescription', validators=[validators.DataRequired(), validators.Length(min=10, max=512)])
    flag = StringField('flag', validators=[validators.DataRequired(), validators.Length(min=5, max=64)])
    problem_difficulty = SelectField('problemDifficulty', choices=[(x, x) for x in range(4)], coerce=int)
    problem_points = SelectField('problemPoints', choices=[(x, diff) for x,diff in zip(range(len(app.config['POINTS'])), app.config['POINTS'])], coerce=int)
    problem_category = SelectField('problemCategory', choices=[(x, cat) for cat,x in zip(app.config['CATEGORIES'], range(len(app.config['CATEGORIES'])))], coerce=int)
    problem_solution = TextAreaField('problemSolution', validators=[validators.DataRequired()])
```

Comment: The question is not clear, by name do you mean the what appears as the input label?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here (and yes that pun is absolutely intended!) is that you have defined a field with `problemName = StringField()`. There is nothing else that this field is called other than 'problemName'.

The text label is a different matter as Moses has commented, your HTML can display anything.